# What is causing this error in Ord instance for complex numbers in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, compare

I'm trying to implement an Ord instance for complex numbers in Haskell. I followed the format I found online for implementing Ord instances but I get an error that I don't understand. The following is my instance code:

```
instance Ord Complex where
 compare (Com x1 y1) (Com x2 y2) 
  | (sqrt ((x1^2)+(y1^2))) < (sqrt ((x2^2)+(y2^2)) = -1 
  | (sqrt ((x1^2)+(y1^2))) == (sqrt ((x2^2)+(y2^2)) = 0 
  | otherwise = 1
```

When I try loading it into GHCI I get this error:

```
Complex.hs:45:52: error:
 parse error on input `='
 Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
 e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
```

But all the examples of Ord instances I've seen use that same format. What's this error?

Comment: The result should be `LT`, `EQ`, `GT`, no?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Better would be just: `instance Ord Complex where compare = comparing (\(Com x y) -> x^2 + y^2)`

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple issues with your code.

1. There are good reasons to *not* give complex number an `Ord` instance. The one you're trying to define gives very counterintuitive results like `-2 > -1`. a more reasonable instance would just compare the real parts, but that is problematic in case they're equal.
   All in all, this is one the instances you'd better just not define.
2. Your clauses are needlessly complicated.

   - Taking the [square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) on both sides of an inequality (with positive values, as ensured by the `(^2)` makes no difference.

     ```
     compare (Com x1 y1) (Com x2 y2) 
       | ((x1^2)+(y1^2)) < ((x2^2)+(y2^2) = -1 
       | ((x1^2)+(y1^2)) == ((x2^2)+(y2^2) = 0
     ```

     This is a really important change, because `sqrt` is substantially more expensive than most other operations, so you definitely don't want to call it four times with no need.
   - You don't need parens around the square expressions, because `infixr 8 ^` binds tighter than `infixl 6 +`.

     ```
     compare (Com x1 y1) (Com x2 y2)
       | (x1^2 + y1^2) < (x2^2 + y2^2 = -1
       | (x1^2 + y1^2) == (x2^2 + y2^2 = 0
     ```

     Ok, at this point it's really obvious what the problem was the compiler complained about: you're missing two closing parens. Or rather, you have *too many opening parens*, because again none of these are actually needed (`infix 4 ==` binds even weaker than `+`).

     ```
     compare (Com x1 y1) (Com x2 y2)
       | x1^2 + y1^2 < x2^2 + y2^2 = -1
       | x1^2 + y1^2 == x2^2 + y2^2 = 0
     ```

     This starts to look decent, but there's still a lot of redundancy: you're computing both sides of the inequality twice. This is probably not too much of a performance, but it still violates [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

     ```
     compare (Com x₁ y₁) (Com x₂ y₂)
       | r₁ < r₂    = -1
       | r₁ == r₂   = 0
       | otherwise  = 1
      where r₁ = x₁^2 + y₁^2
            r₂ = x₂^2 + y₂^2
     ```
3. As already said, `compare` should not yield `-1` `0` `1` but `LT` `GT` or `EQ`.

   ```
   compare (Com x₁ y₁) (Com x₂ y₂)
     | r₁ < r₂    = LT
     | r₁ == r₂   = EQ
     | otherwise  = GT
    where r₁ = x₁^2 + y₁^2
          r₂ = x₂^2 + y₂^2
   ```

   But those guards are so standard that you don't need to write them out: just invoke `compare` (the already-defined `Double` instance) again on the `r` values:

   ```
   compare (Com x₁ y₁) (Com x₂ y₂) = compare r₁ r₂
    where r₁ = x₁^2 + y₁^2
          r₂ = x₂^2 + y₂^2
   ```

   You might now also again inline the variables:

   ```
   compare (Com x₁ y₁) (Com x₂ y₂) = compare (x₁^2 + y₁^2) (x₂^2 + y₂^2)
   ```

Comment: Just to amplify on point 1, there are laws that all Ord instances should follow. One of these is that (compare x y == EQ) implies (x == y), which your definition doesn't obey.

Answer (score 2):

Unbalanced parentheses in both clauses. You're missing a close paren.